# Migrating items from columns residing in different sql tables(5 to 10) to single SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql

I have SQL database where there is a master table and several child tables. There is a key column (id). What I want is to migrate all these column values from multiple tables to one pre-created SharePoint list.(Many to one)

What would be the best way to achieve this. 
Note: the list is already created with all the required columns and required forms for data submission.

One plan that I have is to use query in SQL server to union or join the table columns export the data to excel(if possible) and then import the same to SharePoint list by simple copy pasting rows.

Not sure if this is the most feasible solution or not.

Comment: It depends on the amount of rows you have, depending on memory (on your client) the process will brake if you try to copy too many rows. but then workaround would be to copy in batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-code (from SharePoint perspective) solution would be to get the data from SQL to Excel, then create new SharePoint list based on the the Excel (Import Spreadsheet in SharePoint). It will create new list, so you cannot import to existing SharePoint list.

If the amount of data is not that much, you can just output the SQL query results to Grid in SQL Server Management Studio, then copy paste the grid to Excel.